# How to use custom price attributes in shopping cart price rule, replacing the regular price?

Tags: product-attribute, shopping-cart-price-rules

What I'm trying to set is a promo shopping cart rule that uses custom price attribute.

**The rule should go like this:**

**If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :**

1. Price in cart  equals or greater than  200.
2. HERE I NEED TO ACTIVATE CUSTOM PRICE ATTRIBUTE

So what I'm trying is to make sure that when a customer reaches a certain amount in shopping cart sub total, the regular price will be replaced with the custom price attribute.

Is this possible and can you help me solve my issue?

Comment: Tiered prices are not sufficient for your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find that [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/shopping-cart-price-rule-recipes)
under

X% off specific products when you order Y or more

Go to price cart rules and then add a rule: 
If all of these conditions are ture:
    If total quantity equals or greater than X then
      whatever your discount or price is....

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. OP needs to switch to use a different price value, which may not be the same percentage across multiple products.

Comment: I mean it says subtotal of the cart so this would fine no ?